# Time Difference in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, scripting, vb6

I have written a program which calculates the time difference between two times.
It calculates the time difference between upto some extent (or few cells appropriately). After `few cells` it writes `garbage values to the rest of the cells`.

Please help me.
See the code below.

```
Sub Average()
Dim LogIn As String
Dim LogOff As String
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer
Dim InTime As Date
Dim OffTime As Date
Row = 1
Col = 2
While (Cells(Row, Col) <> "")
Workbooks("Log-In-Time.xlsm").Activate
InTime = Cells(Row, Col)
Workbooks("Log-Off-Time.xlsm").Activate
OffTime = Cells(Row, Col)
Workbooks("Log-In-Time.xlsm").Activate
Cells(Row, Col + 1) = CDate(OffTime) - CDate(InTime)'<- Without CDate also I have tried but output was same.
Row = Row + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

My Log-In-Time.xls content is,

```
                           OUTPUT
7/11/2013   11:35:41 AM 7:14:15 AM
7/15/2013   11:05:22 AM 10:03:00 AM
7/16/2013   9:58:25 AM  11:11:31 AM
7/17/2013   10:33:20 AM 10:39:25 AM
7/18/2013   11:10:33 AM 6:58:35 AM
7/19/2013   12:18:59 AM 7:18:09 PM <-----Here onwadrs
7/22/2013   11:58:26 AM 0.370185185
7/23/2013   11:27:14 AM 0.418645833
7/24/2013   10:59:36 AM 0.439953704
7/25/2013   11:20:16 AM 0.382650463
7/26/2013   11:09:14 AM 0.373171296
```

Log-Off-Time.xls contents are,

```
7/11/2013   6:49:56 PM
7/15/2013   9:08:22 PM
7/16/2013   9:09:56 PM
7/17/2013   9:12:45 PM
7/18/2013   6:09:08 PM
7/19/2013   7:37:08 PM
7/22/2013   8:51:30 PM
7/23/2013   9:30:05 PM
7/24/2013   9:33:08 PM
7/25/2013   8:31:17 PM
7/26/2013   8:06:36 PM
```

Comment: does updating the format of the cells not fix the issue?

Comment: @Jaycal: I could not able to get your question properly? Could you pls refresh your question?

Comment: If you update the Number format of your Output column to "Time", does that not fix the issue?

Comment: When I manually trying for differentiation, it is happening. Like in Cells `='[Log-Off-Time.xlsm]Sheet1'!$F$10 - G14`. It gives write answer. But why problem in VBA?

Comment: @Jaycal: No it is not.

Comment: @Jaycal: I found my answer. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the answer...

Just added the code below.

`Dim Diff As Date`

`Diff = CDate(OffTime) - CDate(InTime)`

Find the complete code below.

```
Sub Average()
Dim LogIn As String
Dim LogOff As String
Dim Diff As Date
Dim Row As Integer
Dim Col As Integer
Dim InTime As Date
Dim OffTime As Date
Row = 1
Col = 2
While (Cells(Row, Col) <> "")
Workbooks("Log-In-Time.xlsm").Activate
InTime = Cells(Row, Col)
Workbooks("Log-Off-Time.xlsm").Activate
OffTime = Cells(Row, Col)
Workbooks("Log-In-Time.xlsm").Activate
Diff = CDate(OffTime) - CDate(InTime)
Cells(Row, Col + 1) = Diff
Row = Row + 1
Wend
End Sub
```